# dev_appengine cannot open a simple Hello World application

Tags: google-app-engine

Suddenly after a system reboot, the dev_appengine stopped working properly.

Any access attempt to the application ends with an error, the admin server is working fine though.

I've also tried with a simple Hello World application but had no luck.

The error is [here](http://pastebin.com/M1Xukjd2) and the sample app is [here](http://pastebin.com/b8RyjmBB).

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a slight error in the handlers section of your app.yaml.  Try this out:

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is nowhere except the app.yaml file, and that too in the line with `url:`

- you could try the answer above 
  or
- try removing the following:-
  `application: hello_world`

`version: 1`

`libraries:
-name: webapp2
 version: "2.5.2"`

IT WORKED FOR ME

- if you want to write `favicon` and `ico` then try adding a `.` after leading slash or changing the backslash after `favicon`